# A function to list all divisors of an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm practicing the basics of Python and I had a exercise of doing a function that asks for the user for a number and the function will return him all the divisors of that number so I done this

```
def divisor_generator():
    integer = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    integer = int(integer)
    list = []
    for divisors in range(integer+1):
        if divisors%integer == 0:
            list.append(divisors)
    print list
```

and for example the output for the integer 50 was

```
[50, 0]
```

I really want to keep it simple and I don't understand what is not good about it, I searched for so many answers but none of them was on my level of understanding. Why is my function not working as expected?

Comment: list is a keyword in python and you should not use it as variable name

Comment: Use `range(1, integer+1)` to avoid the `Division by zero` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modulo is backwards.

Your example is evaluating to `i % 50` when you want `50 % i`.

Answer (score 2):

Your division is backwards.

I think you meant:

```
# I took the s off of "divisors" since it's actually a single number
integer % divisor == 0
```

---

Think of it this way, if `integer` is 50, and `divisor` is 2, with the way you had it, it would be:

```
2 % 50 == 0
```

If numerator is less than the denominator, that check will never be true, except for the when the numbers are the same. I always walk myself through this mental check just to make sure I didn't accidentally put the numbers backwards.

---

And, as mentioned in the comments, don't create variables called `list`. `list` is a built in function, and shadowing it has the potential to cause errors later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct version (I am using `python 3.6.1`). You need to switch the position of `integer` and `divisors`. And you need to start your range from `1` otherwise you get `division by zero` error

```
def divisor_generator():
    integer = input("Enter a number:")
    integer = int(integer)
    list = []
    for divisors in range(1, integer+1):
        if integer%divisors == 0:
            list.append(divisors)
    print (list)
```

By the way, in case you are also interested in a bit concise and different solution to your problem, here is another solution (you don't need it though necessarily):

```
integer = int(input("Enter a number:"))
divisors = [i for i in range(1, integer+1) if integer%i == 0]
print (divisors)
```

Comment: Thanks that answered my question! plsu thnx for second solution but i didnt understand how you did all the for loopls and the i before the for loop all in one line only

Comment: Ok, let me explain: The second method is called `List comprehension`. Basically, you are looping over a `range` with a `for` loop using a variable `i` which is same as your `divisors` (you can use any name). Then you check if the `integer` is divisible by this number `i`. You put this `if` condition after the `for` loop. Now if the condition is True, you need that particular `i` as a divisor and you store it simply by writing `i` before the `for` loop. If the condition is False, the `i` doesn't get stored in the list. This way only those `i` values will be stored in list which are divisors.

Comment: The following link provides more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you very much i looked over List Comprehensions now i understand it better